# Подключение к базе данных из сервера

Tags: c#, база-данных, postgresql, сервер, orm

Реализую сервер который 24 на 7 будет работать с базой данных и должен постоянно обрабатывать запросы от всех пользователей, на всех примерах по работе с БД вижу что после выполнения запросов идет отключение от базы данных, соответственно вопрос: Обязательно ли при каждом запросе подключатся к базе данных? поскольку выходит что один запрос пользователя будет выглядеть как подключение, получение данных, отключение.

Можно ли реализовать подключение во время инициализации сервера и все время держать его открытым ?

Стек: C# Drapper + Postgre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> На всех примерах по работе с БД вижу что после выполнения запросов идет отключение от базы данных, соответственно вопрос: Обязательно ли при каждом запросе подключатся к базе данных? поскольку выходит что один запрос пользователя будет выглядеть как подключение, получение данных, отключение.

Да, обязательно. Дело в том, что в npgsql, как и почти во всех других клиентах для SQL в  реализован механизм Connection Pooling.

`NpgsqlConnection` - это не реальное сетевое соединение к базе. Это "одолженное" на время соединение из общего пула долгоживущих соединений.

Когда вы вызываете `NpgsqlConnection.Open()` - этому экземпляру `NpgsqlConnection` выделяется уже открытое соединение из пула. И только если в пуле свободных открытых соединений не оказалось - создается новое физическое соединение.

При вызове `NpgsqlConnection.Close()/Dispose()` реальное соединение не закрывается, а просто возвращается в пул.

Поэтому самым эффективным по переиспользованию подключений является именно

```
using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open(); // получение соединение из пула
    ...// получение данных
}   // возврат соединения в пул
```

Т.к. чем быстрее вы отдадите соединение в пул - тем меньше шанс, что другому потоку соединений в пуле не хватит, и ему открывать реальное соединение при вызове `Open`.

Comment: + лучше заюзать pgbouncer

Comment: @SultanovShamil не работал с PG, но вроде как pgbouncer - это для тех клиентов, которые сами не умеют пулинг. Зачем он под Npgsql?

Answer (score 0):

В рамках одного подключения нельзя реализовать одновременное выполнение запросов. Если у вас есть http запросы, которые долго выполняются то следует либо объединить несколько запросов к бд в один, либо оптимизировать сам запрос, либо масштабировать бд так, чтобы она выдерживала нагрузку.